# Sklearn's MultiOutputClassifier Does Sometimes Output No Classes in a Multi-label Multi-class Classification Task

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

When using Sklearn's MultiOutputClassifier with any model, e.g. XGBClassifier, KNN, etc., for some samples the binarized output comes out as all zeros meaning that no-labels get picked in the multi-label multi-class classification.

Imagine, you have four classes [c1,c2,c3,c4], then you designate the target variable for a sample that belongs to classes c1 and c4 in a multi-label multi-class classification task as [1,0,0,1]. Now, you can train a MultiOutputClassifier for such a multi-label multi-class classification task. Doing so for some samples you may end up with a predicted target variable in this example as [0,0,0,0], which this implies the given sample upon infering from the trained model, belongs to none of the classes c1,c2,c3 or c4.

I believe this is happening since the MultiOutputClassifier basically fits one classifier for each label, and when a predicted target variable comes out as [0,0,0,0] it means that each classifier for each of the labels c1,c2,c3 or c4, decides that the sample does not belong to the corresponding label that each of them is trying to predict.

So now, given my point on this, is there a way of going around this? and forcing a MultiOutputClassifier to always output designation to at least one label, or at least the most probable label(s)?

Any other approaches you would suggest for this? Or you think it's okay this happen? In that case at inference time, we need to add an additional label where indicates 'no-class' besides the labels c1,c2,c3,c4 in the example above.

Comment: You can try encoding the classes into 3 variables instead of 4 such that [0,0,0]  represents class c1, [1,0,0] represents class c2 and so on.

Comment: @HasanBhagat no, that doesn't work, if your true number of classes be n then you end up having n+1 classes where +1 is when no label gets picked.